# How to use vue to scroll the scroll to the position of the latest message when a new message is generated?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I hope that after I input a new message, the window can instantly move to the bottom of the blue block to see the latest message!
After trying for a long time, I haven't realized it. I would like to ask you what can you do to achieve this `effect`?
thank you all.

[example](https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/LYyaGXM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on the chat window:

```html
<template>
  <div class="chat" ref="chatWindow">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

That lets you access the chat window in `<script>` with `this.$refs.chatWindow`.

In `sendmessage()`, set the chat window's `scrollTop` to `scrollHeight` in the [next tick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) (after the new message is rendered in the chat list):

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    sendmessage() {
      this.paragraph.push({
        content: this.message
      })
      this.message = ''

      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.chatWindow.scrollTop = this.$refs.chatWindow.scrollHeight
      })
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gOWErvm)